# Android Render Script

Tags: android, renderscript

Did any one know about **Renderscript** in android 3.0

Also I want to know the difference between **OpenGL** and **RenderScript**

If you know provide me some good example or demo link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a great deal of information. I assume better documentation is forthcoming at some point. But for the moment I think this is the bulk of it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html

I think the docs explain how OpenGL and Renderscript work together.

And definitely check out the samples.

Answer (score 0):

*Also i want to know the difference between OpenGL and RenderScript*

Both a `renderscript` and `openGL` are used for getting high performance `graphics` and `animation`s.But still `openGL` is the best option to get high performance graphics because it is well documented and you will have more control over the `GLSurfaceView`.But in `renderscript` some of the classes are **depreciated** in the current versions .Its almost not possible to make a `RSSurfaceView` to `transparent`.

some of the example for OenGL [here](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali)

for renderscript you can find [here](https://github.com/ahmedammar/renderscript-examples)